# Problems with my NVIDIA RTX 2070 in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I started modelling and animating in blender 2.79 and transfered everything to Blender 2.8 just to render, but my rendertimes are far to high.

At first i thought i just have to many faces in my scene, but the taskmanager of Windows showed me something rather odd: In GPU rendering mode only 3-10% of the GPU is used, but 100% of the CPU. [image: Screenshot of the Taskmanager]

What could be the reason for that?
Just this night I loaded new drivers for the GPU.

Comment: Make sure that the RTX is enabled in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > System*) in the CUDA tab. If you have both CPU and GPU selected, then both will be used. If your scene is simple you may not see full utilization of the GPU.

Comment: thanks @rjg i had the RTX Graphic card checked together with the cpu and tried to let only the gpu work. In both cases i get rendering times of over 20 minutes for a frame. I think my scene isn't the simplest, but it clearly isn't the the most expensive.

Comment: As long as it's significantly faster than CPU only, it's working correctly. Using 3000  samples does take some time, especially if you're rendering at a high resolution.

Comment: So It's normal, that it only uses 8% of my GPU? seems like a waste to me

Comment: Does it also use only 8% when using just the GPU (CPU unchecked in the CUDA tab)? It will use the maximum that is required to get the job done, unless there is a bug that I'm not aware of.